# Creating multiple files from text editor

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to create many files from one buffer.  Is there an easy way to do this?  So starting with

```
foo1.txt
1a
1b
1c
1d

foo2.txt
2a
2b
2c
2d

foo3.txt
3a
3b
3c
3d
```

make 3 files, named foo 1 2 and 3 .txt, with the contents.

Is there something less cluncky than this?

```
echo 1a > foo1.txt
echo 1b >> foo1.txt
echo 1c >> foo1.txt
echo 1d >> foo1.txt
```

Edit: sorry, the 1a, 1b etc. is meant to symbolize more complex content that I am doing find/replace to in the text editor. I think HERE docs was what I was looking for. Cheers

Comment: which text editor are you using?

Comment: `for suffix in {1..3}; do echo "whatever" >> "foo${suffix}.txt"; done`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write multi line files with cat and [heredocs](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
cat > foo1.txt <<EOF
1a
1b
1c
1d
EOF

cat > foo2.txt <<EOF
2a
2b
2c
2d
EOF

cat > foo3.txt <<EOF
3a
3b
3c
3d
EOF
```

This will allow variable expansion, so:

```
cat > test.txt <<EOF
$HOME
EOF
```

Will produce a file with the path to your home directory. You can supress this by:

```
cat > test.txt <<"EOF"
$HOME
EOF
```

Which will produce a file with the contents `$HOME` rather then the path to your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?:

```
$ printf '1a\n1b\n1c\n1d\n' > foo1.txt
$ cat foo1.txt
1a
1b
1c
1d
```

Or maybe:

```
for i in 1 2 3; do for j in a b c d ; do echo "$i""$j" >> foo"$i".txt ; done ; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on James's answer above but slightly more concise-

```
   for i in {1..3} #Better if you have to do a lot of files
    do 
        for j in {a..d} #Ditto as above comment
        do 
            echo "$i""$j" >> foo"$i".txt 
        done 
    done
```

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question doesn't match the question itself, because there is no text editor involved, but maybe you are looking for HERE documents:

```
    cat >foo1.txt <<EOT
1a
1b
1c
1d
EOT
```

Comment: Sorry, the 1a 1b etc. was meant to symbolize content, I'm using the text editor to find/replace etc.  I think HERE documents is what I was looking for though, thanks!

Comment: In this case, please select the answer as accepted, to show that you don't need more suggestions on this topic.